# What is the meaning of "Who has taken you from crayons to perfume?"

Tags: songs, poetic

Its To Sir, With Love song, from Lulu.

Comment: From childhood to adulthood.

Comment: And how about who has taken you? I don't really understand it.

Comment: He was her teacher: he has taken (accompanied, guided) her from childhood to adulthood.

Comment: This is not a question relating to language usage as defined in the [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Discussing the meaning of song lyrics is on-topic at our sibling site, [Writing.SE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To first understand this line, [please refer to this article on answers.com](https://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_meaning_behind_the_song_'To_Sir_With_Love'_by_Lulu), which has provided some much needed context:

> Lulu is singing about their teacher, a black man, who "took them from
>   crayons to perfume", taught them right from wrong, and how do they
>   repay him for all he has done for them.

According to this curriculum overview written by [Myron Greenfield of University of Houston](https://ssl.uh.edu/honors/Programs-Minors/honors-and-the-schools/houston-teachers-institute/curriculum-units/pdfs/1999/the-united-states-in-the-1960s/greenfield-99-1960s.pdf):

> **“From Crayons to Perfume”** refers to a lyric from the theme song from “To Sir With 
>   Love,” a benchmark of 1960s school cinema. No matter who we were, no matter where 
>   we lived, we began the decade with crayons, and finished it wearing perfume.  We grew 
>   up, whether we wanted to or not.

the line is simply a more poetic way to express that the teacher had accompanied Lulu from when they were still a child, hence **crayon**, up until they became an adult, hence **perfume**.